# prove that sin(θ-Φ)=sinθcosΦ-cosΦsinθ using vector algebra

Tags: vectors

1. The problem statement, all variables and given/known data given two unit vectors a= cosθi + sinθi b=cosΦi+sinΦj prove that sin(θ-Φ)=sinθcosΦ-cosΦsinθ using vector algebra
2. Relevant equations sin(θ-Φ)=sinθcosΦ-cosΦsinθ
3. The attempt at a solution axb= (cosθsinΦ-cosΦsinθ)k and I'm guessing that the change in sign has something to do with the fact that k is perpendicular to the vectors I'm usingΦ-θ

when I calculated the components I got axb = ( cosθi +sinθj )x(cosΦi + sinΦj) axb=cosθcosΦixi + cosθsinΦixj +sinθcosΦjxi +sinθsinΦjxj ixi=1x1xsino=0 jxjxsin0=0 ixj=1x1sin90=1 and jxi=-1 because AxB=-BxA and was then left with axb= cosθsinΦ(1) + sinθcosΦ(-1)=cosθsinΦ -sinθcosΦ but its supposed to be the other way around, I dont understand where I'm going wrong :(

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

use the dot product for $\vec a =(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)^T$ and $\vec b =(\cos \phi, \sin \phi)^T$:
$$
\vec a \cdot \vec b= |a||b| \cos (\theta-\phi)=\cos (\theta-\phi)=\cos \theta \cos \phi +\sin \theta \sin \phi
$$
than find
$$
 \sin(\theta -\phi)=\sqrt{1-\cos^2 (\theta-\phi)}
$$

Comment: Nice :). Very elegant way. Couldn't we expand this method to 3 dimenional vectors and get it directly using the cross-product?

Comment: e In 3D the components of the vectors can be expressed by means of the  direction cosines and the relation is not so immediate.

Comment: no i meant $a=(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha,0), b=(\cos\phi,\sin\phi,0)$. Apply the cross product and dertermin the magnitude of the cross product.